# Invalid image in attachment

Tags: python-3.x, email, mime

I used SMTP to send images through mail. It can send mail, but the images can't be opened; it said unsupported format. The image was taken using opencv. Here is the code I used. Please tell me what I did wrong in the program. There is no error but the image can't opened.

Cods:

```
import cv2
i=0

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if(i==0):
     for i in range(1):
           return_value, image = camera.read()
           cv2.imwrite('Disease'+str(i)+'.png', image)


import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 

fromaddr = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
toaddr = "yyyyyy@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart() 
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr 
msg['Subject'] = "DISEASE"
body = "FOR NOTIFICATION"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 

filename = "Disease.png"
attachment = open("C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/capture.py", "rb") 

p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream') 
p.set_payload((attachment).read()) 
encoders.encode_base64(p) 
p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 

msg.attach(p) 

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
s.starttls() 
s.login(fromaddr, "password") 

text = msg.as_string() 

s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) 
s.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Sending images is perfectly well supported. Probably you are doing something wrong when you attempt to construct the email message, but without any code for us to look at, this question is basically unresolvable, and should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: sorry i'll add the code.Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching a piece of Python code and claiming that it is an image. I imagine you probably want to run that code and attach its output.

Assuming `C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/capture.py` is the path to the code which you included which creates the image, and that `C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/` is on your `PYTHONPATH`, you simply want to

```
import disease
```

though arguably, a better design is to restructure this file so that it declares a function you can call when you need to, rather than running the code exactly once immediately when you `import` it; the standard mechanism for this is

```
def functionname():
    # ... Your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    functionname()
```

and the way to import *and call* this code is then

```
import disease

# ... Other code ...
disease.functionname()
```

(Obviously, a better name than `functionname` would be something properly descriptive, like `generate_png`.)

Perhaps you might want to avoid writing the image to disk at all if you are only using it to attach it to an email message and then discarding it, but as this is somewhat speculative, and hitting the disk is not a major efficiency problem, I won't elaborate on that at this point.

As another detail, you are attaching the image as a generic `application/octet-stream` body part. Images have their own designated MIME types; you'll want `image/png` for a PNG picture.

The Python class for this type of attachment is `MIMEImage`.

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

# ...
image_filename = './Disease.png'
image = MIMEImage(open(image_filename, 'rb').read(), name=os.path.basename(image_filename))
msg.attach(image)
```

The class generally already knows how to set detailed attributes like the precise image type and the content disposition and transfer encoding.

As a stylistic aside, `import` statements should generally be at the top of the file; see [PEP-8.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Oh, your code creates `Disease0.png`, not `Disease.png`

Comment: As an aside, the `email` library was overhauled in Python 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Modern code should no longer use the `MIMEImage` etc classes. Perhaps review the [examples from the `email` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) to see what the code should look like these days.